# Ros indigo Re-installation problem

Tags: ros, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I installed ROS indigo first and then I tried to install ROS jade as well. I could install both ROS and switch between them successfully, However installation of jade totally replaced gazebo2.2 by gazebo5. Consequently I could not do any simulation in indigo. I decided to remove both ROS and Gazebo and reinstall the indigo, but I receive the below error when I try “sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-desktop-full”

```
Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree        Reading state information... Done Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable distribution that some required packages have not yet been created or been moved out of Incoming. The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:  ros-indigo-desktop-full : Depends: ros-indigo-simulators but it is not going to be installed E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/211291/ros-indigo-re-installation-problem/) by [shervin](https://answers.ros.org/users/22781/shervin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 166 on 2015-06-14

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I think I found the solution. If any one facing the same problem please fallow the below steps:

```
sudo apt-get remove gazeboX #X is the version of gazebo you installed in my case 5
sudo apt-get install libsdformat1
```

then you should be able to install indigo again

Sherrvin

---

Originally posted by [shervin](https://answers.ros.org/users/22781/shervin/) with karma: 166 on 2015-06-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 13

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SMAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/25203/sman/) on 2015-11-30**:
Worked like a charm

**Comment by [ffsephirot](https://answers.ros.org/users/27603/ffsephirot/) on 2016-07-26**:
Thank you a lot! :)

**Comment by [Yuxi](https://answers.ros.org/users/27784/yuxi/) on 2016-08-25**:
Thanks a lot !!

**Comment by [Teagan Li](https://answers.ros.org/users/27937/teagan-li/) on 2016-09-08**:
Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

better using  $ sudo apt-get remove gazebo*

---

Originally posted by [mereTeresa](https://answers.ros.org/users/25911/mereteresa/) with karma: 11 on 2016-02-10

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1